# Validation rule for close won opportunity

Tags: formula, validation, validation-rule

I'm trying to create a validation rule that when an opportunity is closed won will not save if the "Contract_Start_Date__c" and "Contract_End_Date_c" is not populated.

I have this:

```
Contract_Start_Date__c=null || Contract_End_Date__c=null
```

No syntax errors, but it does not work.

I also have this:

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won"),
  (Contract_Start_Date__c=null || Contract_End_Date__c=null))
```

No syntax errors there either, but it did not work either. :-(

Any advice to correct these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ISBLANK() formula instead of comparing to null.

```
AND(ISPICKVAL(StageName, "Closed Won"), ISBLANK(Contract_Start_Date__c) || ISBLANK(Contract_End_Date__c))
```

Comment: I did notice it would not work until I deactivated another validation rule I had on another field. I would have thought I could have multiple validation rules that will prevent Users from closing an Opportunity "Closed Won".